# data from database is not showing in html template in django

Tags: html, mysql, django

I fetched data from books table in views.py and passed to show.html as dictionary.It is not showing.also i wanted to check if there is key passed in html..so purposely wrote paragraph after {%if key1 %} ,it is not showing that paragraph also.what will be the reason or my fault?

here is my code snippet

#### views.py

```
def show(request):  
    books = Books.objects.all()  
    return render(request,'app/show.html',{'key1':books})
```

#### urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [path("",views.index,name = 'home'),  
path('show/',views.show,name= 'show'),
]
```

#### models.py

```
class Books(models.Model):  
    book_num = models.IntegerField()  
    auth_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)  
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)  
    def __str__(self):  
        return self.auth_name
```

#### show.html

```
<center>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <th>Available books</th>
        {%if key1%}
            <P>please check if issued</p>
            {% for i in key1 %}
                <tr>
                    <td>Author name:{{i.auth_name}}</td>
                    <td>Book title:{{i.book_name}}</td>    
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}   
      </tbody>
    </table>
</center>
```

Comment: Do you really have any records in the database?

Comment: yes..total 9 records..i am able to populate database from html but can not get reverse.

Comment: It will display data in the template, may be the issue with another thing.

Comment: Do you getting any error or just blank template?

Comment: problem i think is this key1 only not reached in html as it is not showing message after that

Comment: @SunderamDubey not getting any error..it displays "available books" at the center..nothing else

Comment: It should be `{% if  key1 %}` with space not `{%if key1%}`

Comment: @AnkitTiwari corrected but still not showing.

Comment: Try to print your `books` variable inside view eg. `print(books)` & before if try to render `key1` template variable eg. `{{key1}}` and let me know if you're getting any data

Comment: @AnkitTiwari i wrote print(books) inside show view and {{key1.auth_name}} before if inside show.html and run server. but it is not showing print value also in terminal and key1 variable also on server

Comment: @AnkitTiwari update: above code is a part of my project.I created another django project with above code only then it is working properly,showing all the data from database table.so i guess there is issue with other code from project.

Comment: thank you all for suggestion,I found out solution.its due to render in other view.i have to redirect show page not render.

Comment: use books instead of key1